# Local HTML-page and Java SE application

Tags: javascript, java, html, ajax

I have a local HTML-page on my pc, example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
Your age: <input type="text" id="yourAge" value="Insert your age, please">
<br>
Server's answer: <input type="text" id="serverAnswer" value="Server's answer">
<br>
<input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="answer.js">
</body>
</html>
```

and I want to send *yourAge* to a Java SE application (example: server pc with IP=192.168.1.1 and port=54321).

My Java application creates an answer like this:

```
...
function String answerServer(int yourAge) {
   if(yourAge<50) 
      return "You are Young";
   else 
      return "Yor are Old";
}
...
```

I want to see the server's answer in the HTML-page, maybe without refresh.

I don't use Apache, Tomcat, IIS, ... 
I must use only HTML5/CSS/Javascript and Java SE (not Java EE!).
Maybe I will use Ajax. Other solutions?

Is it possible? Is there an example on the Net to start the development?

Comment: This seems like an odd set of requirements. If interacting with a web browser (I am assuming you are viewing your html file in a browser), why not run Tomcat? The logical solution would be to either web-enable your application (using Tomcat or otherwise), or ditch the HTML page and add a GUI to your java app...

Comment: Sorry, I can't use Tomcat :-(
Other solution?

Comment: Why not? Why these requirements? Is any application server off limits or just Tomcat? How about embedding tomcat within your app? Something like ajax requires a webserver - which an application server can provide for you. Or the alternative I mentioned: adding a GUI to your java application instead of using an HTML page? Having a better picture of your situation will improve our ability to suggest solutions!

Comment: Hi brain99, I can't use Tomcat because, my teacher (it is a college project) says to me: "The communication, between HTML-local-website and Java-SE-server, using Ajax. No Tomcat, Apache and others."
So, is it possible?

Comment: The problem with this type of question is that we don't have the proper context. What have you learned so far? What is the scope of the assignment? Seeing as it's a homework assignment, there can be any number of arbitrary restrictions we don't know about so any suggestions we make is like flying blind. There are still a number of ways to approach this - going from embedding tomcat into your application up to implementing a webserver yourself from scratch with a number of options in between. We cannot know which path the teacher intends for you to take.